# Как вывести элементы верхнего уровня в каталоге в bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

Имеется сайт на битрикс  20.0 ("Управление сайтом"). Загрузил товары в этот сайт из 1с Предприятие 8.3 (конфигурация УНФ). Товары вижу в админ-панели (они у меня одного уровня, без категорий/разделов). Хочу вывести в публичной части сайта список товаров (в мой-сайт.рф/catalog), но он не выводится (страница существует, но товары не отображаются). Если создать раздел в этом каталоге, и в нем уже какой-нибудь тестовый товар, то внутри мой-сайт.рф/catalog отображается раздел, а если в него (раздел) зайти, то там будет отображаться этот самый товар. То есть проблема именно с отображением товаров верхнего уровня. Как все-таки вывести товары верхнего уровня? Читал здесь - https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog.php, в частности, есть фраза:

"Внимание! Компонент не работает с инфоблоками, не имеющими структуры разделов. Если по логике проекта информация не должна иметь структурного деления, то необходимо создать один раздел верхнего уровня и уже в нём размещать элементы инфоблока"

Так и не понял, что именно нужно сделать для решения данной проблемы. Сейчас у меня один инфоблок - "основной каталог товаров" (каталог /catalog), и не мне на данный момент не нужны разделы внутри /catalog.

Как можно победить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

использовать не компонент каталога а сразу https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/catalog/catalog_section.php с параметром

```
SHOW_ALL_WO_SECTION=>"Y",
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ, помогло подключение компонента bitrix:catalog.section в sections.php. Осталось решить проблему отображения страницы с товаром верхнего уровня - при клике по мой-сайт.рф/catalog/tovar пишет что "раздел не существует". При этом с товаром из вложенного раздела мой-сайт.рф/catalog/razdel/tovar2 все в порядке. Не знаете ли как это решить?

Comment: p.s. Кстати, обнаружил, что по адресу вида мой.сайт-рф/catalog/abrakadabra/tovar страничка с товаром открывается (abrakadabra - рандомное слово), при этом внизу характеристик товара вижу "Раздел не найден". Такая вот фишка/баг/особенность